# The primary container for production variant default-variant-name did not pass the ping health check. Please check CloudWatch logs for this endpoint

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to deploy a pre-trained ML model in Sagemaker.

Whenever I try to deploy the model, I get this error:

```
The primary container for production variant default-variant-name did not pass the 
ping health check. Please check CloudWatch logs for this endpoint.
```

in Endpoint Console and I get this

```
169.254.178.2 - - [06/Oct/2022:05:43:42 +0000] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "AHC/2.0"
```

in Cloudwatch logs.

ML model is of pickle format, I have converted it into tar.gz and stored the file in S3.

serve.py file -

```
import json
import joblib
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm
import os
import sklearn
import pickle
import boto3
import pickle
import tarfile

def init():

    global model
    s3_bucket = 'sagemaker-model-artifacts-dt'

    model_filename = 'svm-model.tar.gz'

    model_s3_key = model_filename

    model_url = f's3://{s3_bucket}/{model_s3_key}'
    print(model_url)
    my_tar = tarfile.open("svm-model.tar.gz")
    my_tar.extractall('./')
    model = pickle.load(open('svm-model.pkl','rb'))
    print(model)

def run(raw_data):
    # Get the input data as a numpy array
    print(raw_data)
    data = np.array(json.loads(raw_data)['data'])
#     data = scaler.transform(data)
    # Get a prediction from the model
    predictions: np.ndarray = model.predict(data)
    # Return the predictions as any JSON serializable format
    return {
        "predictions": predictions.tolist()
    }
```

Dockerfile -

```
FROM python:latest

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
         wget \
         python3 \
         nginx \
         ca-certificates \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && python3 get-pip.py && \
    pip install joblib numpy sklearn boto3 && \
        rm -rf /root/.cache

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=TRUE
ENV PATH="/opt/program:${PATH}"

COPY service_files /opt/program

WORKDIR /opt/program

ENTRYPOINT ["python","/opt/program/serve.py"]
```

Comment: Have you checked the memory usage of your endpoint in the cloudwatch metrics. May by loading the model you get an OOM. SVM model can become very big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for taking time in going through my query.

I tried using one more method which was using [ezsmdeploy](https://github.com/aws-samples/easy-amazon-sagemaker-deployments#installing-the-ezsmdeploy-python-sdk) and it worked. I would suggest that approach if you already have a pre-trained model and dont want to deal with docker.